# How to perform a $and search with Python and MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb

Let's say I have a list of keywords and I want to match against MongoDB documents in which they all appear in the `keys` field (that is, a AND clause).

How can I do that in Python?

I've tried:

```
keywords = ['a', 'b', 'c']
keywords_dict = {'keys' : keywords}
results = collection.find(keywords_dict)
```

But it seems to return no result.

I'm using Python3.5 with PyMongo.

Any hints?

Comment: I've figured it out: I need to make a list of dictionaries, e.g. `{ '$and' : [ {'keys' : key1} , {'keys' : key2} ] }` - any hints on other ways to do this is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **[`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/)** operator which is also equivalent to an **[`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#op._S_and)** operation of the specified values; i.e. the following statement:

```
{ 'keys': { '$all': ['a', 'b', 'c'] } }
```

is equivalent to:

```
{ '$and': [ { 'key': a }, { 'key': b }, { 'key': c} ] }
```